# sql query about string function

Tags: sql, string

```
ID  MOBILE 
1   9869600733 
2   9869600793 
3   9869600799
```

all id whose mobile number containing 9 three times(using string functions like replace, substr, etc)... ? (without like , % , etc)

Comment: Which DBMS you are using ?

Comment: exactly three times? or at least three times?

Comment: both exactly 3 & more than 3 as well...

Comment: And why not `like`?  That is the appropriate way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `LEN` and `Replace`

```
Where len(MOBILE)-len(replace(MOBILE ,'9',''))>=3
```

**Note :** Some `DBMS` uses `LENGTH` instead of `LEN`

```
Where length(MOBILE)-length(replace(MOBILE ,'9',''))>=3
```

- [**DEMO**](http://rextester.com/VPHQTZ76677)

---

- `replace(MOBILE ,'9','')` will replace all the `9's` with empty
  string
- `length(MOBILE)` will count the number of characters in `Mobile`
  column
- `length(replace(MOBILE ,'9',''))` will count the number of characters
  in `Mobile` column as replacing `9's` with empty string
- `length(MOBILE)-length(replace(MOBILE ,'9',''))` here the
  difference will tell the number of missing characters that is our `9`, you can use this difference to count the `9`

Comment: can u pls tell me logic

Comment: i need another help from you

Comment: @PrashantTendulkar - yes

Comment: want to write a check constraint(while creating a table) which accepts value between 2 dates like ('25-oct-94' to '10-may-16')

Comment: create table dob5 ( birthdate date, CONSTRAINT check_dates CHECK (birthdate BETWEEN '25-oct-94' AND '10-may-16') ) this is how i tried @Pரதீப்

Comment: @PrashantTendulkar - close this question by selecting tick mark to the left of this answer and ask a new question with your effort..

Comment: it gives error @Rahul :- "date or system variable wrongly specified in CHECK constraint "

Comment: actually i extended limit of asking questions so can u pls tell me here ?

Comment: @PrashantTendulkar - Which DBMS you are using ?

Comment: i am using oracle
and there is 2 query 
1. accept the date between 2 dates using check constraint
2. accept the date which is less than year 2000 using check constraint...

i tried a lot but its not working

Comment: @PrashantTendulkar `create table dob5 ( birthdate date, CONSTRAINT check_dates CHECK (birthdate BETWEEN date '1994-10-25' AND date '2016-05-20') )`

Comment: and for before the year of 2000
only 2000

Comment: @PrashantTendulkar `create table dob ( birthdate date, 
                   yearcheckcol date,
                   CONSTRAINT check_dates CHECK (birthdate BETWEEN date '1994-10-25' AND date '2016-05-20'),
                    CONSTRAINT check_year CHECK (EXTRACT(month FROM yearcheckcol) <=2000)
                  )`

Comment: it gives error :- " name already used by an existing constraint "

Comment: its working...
while creating table it takes date in this format '1994-10-25'

but while inserting values it does not take date in this format .. it takes date ' 27-oct-1995 ' in this format... 
why this happened ?

Comment: table is created @Pரதீப்

create table do7 
(yearch date,
CONSTRAINT check_dates CHECK (EXTRACT(month FROM yearch) <=2000) 
)

insert into do7 values('25-oct-1999'') its accepted
insert into do7 values('25-oct-2002') but this date is also accepted which is more than year 2000 

pls give me solution bro

Answer (score 1):

exactly three '9's:

```
Select * from mytable
Where len(mobile) - len(replace(mobile, '9', '')) = 3
```

at least three '9's:

```
Select * from mytable
Where len(mobile) - len(replace(mobile, '9', '')) >= 3
```

Comment: can you tell me logic of this ?

Comment: Yes, if you create a string that has all the `9`s removed, then it's length will be the length of the unmodified string minus the number of `9`s that were removed.